# Expose or consume API REST?

Tags: design, architecture, api, api-design, single-responsibility

I am preparing the software architecture for my client project based on APIs REST
The idea is that any data exchange between my client and his partner will be via API REST  call

The specification is that my client have a large data store ( SQL database) which must me updated by data got from the partner

My question is :

1. Should My client expose a POST API REST  so that the partner invoke this POST HTTP and carry out the data in the payload to update our store (DB)
2. Should the partner expose a GET HTTP API and my client just invoke the GET API (exposed by the partner) , the client get the data from the payload and update itself the store ?

Is there any criteria which I should consider when I decide in such scenarios ?
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who decides when the client's DB needs to be updated? Because that party will be the one sending the request.

Maybe the client only wants to update their database once. Maybe the client wants to receive every update the moment it is available. We can't know that.

This is something *you* have to analyze, to understand the requirements.

Comment: @BenhassineMohamed: There's your answer then.

Comment: Thanks for your response When the partner has fresh data in his data store , HE DECIDES to push data to my client so the PARTNER IS THE ONE WHO DECIDE we have 2  solution :   
  
SOLUTION 1 : Partner expose GET API REST and SEND an event ( broker) to my client so the later is informed that he should GET the data from the PARTNER and update his DB     

SOLUTION2 : My Client Expose API POST and the Partner invoke the API POST ( published by my clinet ) to update data in client's DB 

what is the best solution and why ? Thanks

Comment: @BenhassineMohamed: Re-read the first paragraph.

Comment: so the Partner will send POST to CLIENT API according to you  ?   but here the partner may expose a GET and the client get informed and send request to get data from partner ? why not ?

Comment: @BenhassineMohamed, KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid). The more complexity you add to your design, the harder it will be to reason about it and to maintain it. So, what is the simplest design that meets your requirements.

Comment: @BenhassineMohamed: Why build two components when one does the job?